# Nginx Redirect js.map , css.map

Tags: nginx

I am receiving multiple 404 errors for .map files which do not exist in my server logs. e.g.

```
/wp-includes/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css.map
/wp-content/plugins/cornerstone/assets/dist/js/site/cs-head.js.map
/wp-content/plugins/cornerstone/assets/dist/js/site/cs-body.js.map
```

How could I set up a redirect on Nginx so that files ending .map are redirected to a blank file called 404.map

In Apache this can be achieved as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

    # Prevent 404 Not Found for javascript/css source maps
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (\.map)$
    RewriteRule (.*)  404.map [QSA]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `error_page` directive. Assuming that `404.map` is placed in the document root, use:

```
location ~ \.map$ {
    error_page 404 /404.map;
}
```

If you want the `404.map` file to be returned with a 200 status response, use:

```
location ~ \.map$ {
    error_page 404 =200 /404.map;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) for details.

---

In retrospect, `error_page` is probably not the answer you are looking for. To test for the existence of a file and return another file if it does not exist, use `try_files`. For example:

```
location ~ \.map$ {
    try_files $uri /404.map;
}
```

An advantage of using `try_files` is that the `[error]...open()...` messages will be suppressed. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: ok but will this 404 redirect, all .map files or just the ones which are missing ?

Comment: Only those that do not exist. If you want all `.map` files to respond with a 404, add `return 404;`

Comment: no I just want the ones missing .. thanks so much. My wordpress site is at var/www/html so I assume I must place 404.map in the html folder

Comment: I am still receiving errors: 2018/11/03 11:03:15 [error] 28190#28190: *26451 open() "/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/x/framework/dist/js/site/x.js.map" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 34xxx.58, server: , request: "GET /wp-content/themes/x/framework/dist/js/site/x.js.map HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"

Comment: perhaps this is an issue with wordpress that interferes with nginx before your location code runs?

Comment: The `[error]` message is normal for files that do not exist, however, you can suppress it using `try_files` - see my updated answer.